# Ionic 4, Capacitor and Electron - ToastController problem

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, capacitor

I created a basic application with Ionic 4 and capacitor. When adding Electron and trying to run the application the following error occurs:

No @ ionic/core ToastController detected, please make sure you have included the web component.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Everton

Comment: Hey, did you solve the problem? If so, it would be very nice if you could provide the solution in here :) maybe as accepted answer, greetz

Comment: Nothing until now

Comment: Change `base href='/'` to `base href='./'` in your *index.html*. The Electron app is working but the toast problem not solved.